# ddev start readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2: invalid argument error

Tags: docker, drupal-8, drupal-commerce, ddev

I am trying to install Drupal Commerce via composer. I have finished the installation but it requires DDEV for local development server and it depends on Docker. I installed both and when i try to start server with "ddev start", i got this error message:

```
Starting environment for drupcom... 
readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2: invalid argument 
Failed to start drupcom: Failed to run docker-compose [-f /Users/....../Documents/Projects/DrupalSites/drupcom/.ddev/docker-compose.yaml up -d], err='exit status 1', stdout='', stderr='readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2: invalid argument'
```

I am using OSX El Capitan. What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: This sure looks like docker isn't installed right or something. It does look like from the conversation in Drupal's #ddev channel that you got this part of your challenge resolved, so probably good to close/remove this, or say how you resolved it.

Comment: Yes this one is resolved, i did a reset to factory and "ddev config" and "ddev start" again, now it works

Comment: I've solved this in another case by deleting the container *and* the image, using `docker rm` and `docker rmi`

Answer (score 2):

can you try this

```
docker-compose down --rmi local 
docker-compose down --rmi all 
docker-compose up
```